# Create JSON multi-level with Json.NET in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i have 2 class:

```
class Employee
{
    string name;
    string age;
}

class Departments
{
    string branch;
    Employee A;
}
```

Declare new list:

```
List<Departments> lstDp = new List<Departments>();
```

after get/set and Add Employee into the list ... i have a LIST of Departments include Employee info. And then:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstDp, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

but the output JSON string only contain element "branch". What's wrong with this? I want the output like this:

```
[
  {
    "branch": "NY",
    "Employee": {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "age": "29",
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: **1)** your fields are not public, they won't be serialized **2)** Your json is not correct. There will be no `Employee` string in the output. It will be `A` **3)** `A` is not a list. It is a single employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be that some of class members is private. Just tested:

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}

class Departments
{
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
var lstDp = new List<Departments> {
            new Departments {
                Branch = "NY",
                Employee = new Employee { Age = "29", Name = "John Smith" }
            }
        };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstDp, Formatting.Indented);
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `Department`should contain an `IEnumerable<Employee>` not just an `Employee`